# CKEDITOR icons not showing

Tags: wysiwyg

My CKEDITOR icons are missing like this,, but the buttons works fine. Just the icons are not displaying.[image: screenshot]

Ive check the icons in in the module and it is located in sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png. I checked the actual link if it will display the icons.png, but i found out that there is something in front of the hostname like this

- unknownnumbers/hostname/root/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png,

and if just remove the unknownnumbers and make it into

- hostname/root/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png

i can now see the image, what's the problem? thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome. First, you must know there are at least 3 ways to implement ckeditor on Drupal page - please make it explicit you are using dedicated CKEditor module. Second, please see your reports under `/admin/reports/dblog` and `/admin/reports/status`. Tell us if anything that might look relevant is there.

Comment: Last but not least, if you think it's a module bug, report to their [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/ckeditor?categories=All).